# How to make SWT Browser control use Mozilla instead of IE on Windows?

Tags: firefox, browser, swt

I want to make SWT use Firefox on all platforms I run my app on. But SWT of course used IE on Windows by default. Any idea how to make SWT use Mozilla on windows. I know that I need to have XULRunner installed on the machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Funny you've asked - I just needed the same for our project.

1. Go to ATF site (http://wiki.eclipse.org/ATF/Installing) - there's how to d/l XUL Runner from Zend site.
2. This code will let you run the browser without registering the XULRunner:

**Code:**

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("org.mozilla.xulrunner"); //$NON-NLS-1$
if (bundle != null) 
{
    URL resourceUrl = bundle.getResource("xulrunner"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    if (resourceUrl != null) {
        try {
            URL fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(resourceUrl);
            File file = new File(fileUrl.toURI());
            System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath",file.getAbsolutePath()); //$NON-NLS-1$
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // log the exception
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // log the exception
        }
    }
}
```

More details here: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusemozilla

**Note:** my code is slightly different from FAQ (different plugin ID) - i works for me this way.

Comment: old. outdated. deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

I just found the answer.

1. You need to have XULRunner registered on your machine. To do so, just unpack it and then execute this command in the command shell `xulrunner.exe --register-global`.
2. Pass the `SWT.MOZILLA` style to Browser constructor: `Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.MOZILLA);`

Comment: I am this error, can't find the solution: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.eclipse.swt.internal.mozilla.init.XPCOMInit.GREVersionRange_sizeof()I

Comment: When I run `xulrunner.exe --register-global`, it tells me that `Error: couldn't parse application.ini`.