# access_token not showing in url in SWT browser

Tags: browser, swt, access-token

I am developing an Eclipse plugin where user needs to login to their Facebook account in an SWT brower. I am using the way, described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) to try to get the access token from the url. It had worked well until today. The problem is that redirected uri is no longer followed by "access_token=..." any more. Then I mannually tried to get the access token from url in real browsers. It works on Chrome and FireFox, not on IE. In my progrm, the SWT browser is defined as follows:

```
Browser browser = new Browser(container, SWT.NONE);
```

I guess it must've used IE in the background and IE for some reason hides the access_token from the url. Any idea for unhiding the access token?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The following answer refers only to the SWT part of your issue.

`org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser` is using a [native renderer](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserplatforms) for each platform it supports.

For Windows the default happens to be IE.

Depending on your use case (i.e. OS, Eclipse versions you need to support), you can [force the widget to use a different native renderer](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserspecifydefault).

Comment: Thanks! I chose "SWT.MOZILLA" as the browser type. And it worked. [Here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086734/how-to-make-swt-browser-control-use-mozilla-instead-of-ie-on-windows) is a post that shows how to enable SWT.MOZILLA within your code.