# Firefox in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, firefox, swt, eclipse-rcp, xulrunner

I'm trying to use Firefox as my SWT Browser that runs inside my Eclipse RCP plugin.

I've tried loading XULRunner using the following code which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086734/how-to-make-swt-browser-control-use-mozilla-instead-of-ie-on-windows):

```
    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(PLUGIN_NAME); //$NON-NLS-1$
    if (bundle != null) {
        URL resourceUrl = bundle.getResource("xulrunner"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        if (resourceUrl != null) {
            try {
                URL fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(resourceUrl);
                File file = new File(fileUrl.toURI());
                System.setProperty(
                        "org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath", "file:///" + file.getAbsolutePath()); //$NON-NLS-1$
                System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType",
                        "mozilla");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    Browser webBrowser = new Browser(parent, SWT.MOZILLA);
```

I'm using Windows 7 x86 and Eclipse Indigo. I have tried XULrunner 3.6.25 and 10. The Firefox version I used were 10 and 22.

No matter what version, it crashes giving this stacktrace:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error -2147467259
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.error(Mozilla.java:2502)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initXULRunner(Mozilla.java:2464)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:672)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:99)
```

If I remove the `file:///` before the path to XULRunner I get the error `c is not a registered protocol` in XULrunner 3.6.25.

Does anybody know what this particular XPCOM error means and how to fix it?

Comment: First google result for "SWTError: XPCOM error": [Bug 174395 - Browser SWTError (XPCOM error -2147467259) when using the SWT 3.3 Broswer widget on Linux with Mozilla 1.7.8](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=174395)

Comment: @Baz: Thanks. As I see it, the bug described is a 64 bit issue. But my environment is purely 32 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086734/how-to-make-swt-browser-control-use-mozilla-instead-of-ie-on-windows?lq=1), these are the steps that made Firefox work for me inside Eclipse:

1. Install the Ajax Tools Framework (http://wiki.eclipse.org/ATF/Installing)
2. Under "Run Configurations..." -> "Plug-ins" add `org.mozilla.xulrunner` and `org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86`
3. Start Firefox within swt.browser using the following code:

   ```
   Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("org.mozilla.xulrunner"); //$NON-NLS-1$  
   if (bundle != null) {
       URL resourceUrl = bundle.getResource("xulrunner"); //$NON-NLS-1$
       if (resourceUrl != null) {
           try {
               URL fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(resourceUrl);
               File file = new File(fileUrl.toURI());
               System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType",
                       "mozilla");
               System.setProperty(
                       "org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath", file.getAbsolutePath()); //$NON-NLS-1$

           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   } else {
       System.err.println("Could not find XULrunner bundle");
   }
   Browser webBrowser = new Browser(parent, SWT.MOZILLA);
   GridData grid = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
   webBrowser.setLayoutData(grid);
   // Prepending "file://" prevents the "<driveletter> is not a registered protocol" error
   String graphUrl = "file://C:/Users/you/yourGraph.html"
   webBrowser.setUrl(graphUrl);
   ```