# Integrate Mozilla Firefox with SWT Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, mozilla

Is there any way to integrate Mozilla Firefox with SWT Eclipse RCP? I have no idea, I can do that.

I am trying to do that like it is on this site [How to make SWT Browser control use Mozilla instead of IE on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086734/how-to-make-swt-browser-control-use-mozilla-instead-of-ie-on-windows)
, but that doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_ ?

Comment: i got exception: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]. Is there way to not use XULRunner? I don't want install it on every machine.