# How to use any browser except IE11 in Eclipse 3.1.1?

Tags: eclipse, internet-explorer, swt, birt, viewer

We are using Birt Viewer Toolkit, BVT, and Eclipse 3.1.1 to display BIRT reports. We are stuck on Eclipse 3.1.1. There is a problem on sites which have installed Internet Explorer 11, the reports do not display. I want to use an older version of Internet Explorer, such as IE 8, 9, 10, or Firefox or Chrome, anything but IE 11.

I found this reference, this is the sort of solution I’m looking for
[How to make SWT Browser control use Mozilla instead of IE on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086734/how-to-make-swt-browser-control-use-mozilla-instead-of-ie-on-windows)
which says you can create a Browser in Eclipse using 
Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.MOZILLA);
SWT.MOZILLA is not defined in Eclipse 3.1.1. Looks like SWT.MOZILLA was started in Eclipse 3.3.

Also looking in org.eclipse.swt.browser. I see Shell.Explorer hardcoded in the call to new WebSite.

How do I use any browser except IE 11, on sites which have IE installed?

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer (IE) is default embedded web browser in Eclipse under Windows there is no option to change default internal web browser. Anyway there you can use one of three options as work around:

1. Update your Eclipse to the latest one. It works correctly with IE 10
2. Try opening your report in Firefox instead of your report viewer (I know that this is not the best option).
3. Change default settings in IE to use compatibility mode. These changes should also apply embedded web browser.